# PowerBuilder 10.5 on Windows 7 environment, Network printer issue with ole control

Tags: powerbuilder

I am migrating the PB application from 9 to 10.5, MS Office 97, 2003 to MS Office 2011 also the Operating System is windows XP to Windows 7.

My problem is while setting/executing application setting the activeprinter from the ole control

`ole_1.object.application.ActivePrinter = "Xerox1W3 on Laxhns73"`

but it showed the error accessing the external object property activeprinter at line ## in function fw_xyz..

But it was worked previously in between they did some server tranfer one location to another location. so i don't why it is not working..

anybody can look into this ASAP.

Thanks in Advance

Pandian R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy observation is that PowerBuilder 10.5 was never supported on Windows 7, so you're taking your chances navigating around issues that were known to Sybase to exist (but not published in a cohesive list, just in bug fix logs) until PowerBuilder 11.5.

Beyond that, this looks like the application behind the OLE control (you haven't mentioned what it is) has changed its OLE interface to exclude the Application.ActivePrinter property. Maybe there's a new version installed on your Windows 7 platform.

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I am using the ole control in my application and also i am using the MS Office 2010 -> Word 2010. Previously i had one issue on mailmerge.it was resolved in registry entry.

Comment: I am using the ole control in my application and also i am using the MS Office 2010 - Word 2010.